# Is it possible to resize a Panel inside another Panel in ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, resize, extjs4

I have some custom panel `A` (inside of which I have a grid with locked columns) of size x:1000, y: 600 that is enclosed by an Ext.TabPanel `B` of smaller size. For some calculations I need to have `A` panel resized to it's full size (meaning 1000*600). Is it possible to achieve that in Ext 4.1 by some combination of suspendLayouts or some other approach ? The definitions of panels :

```
A = new Ext.panel.Panel({
    height      : 600,
    width       : 1000

});

B = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab : 0,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    height:450,
    width: 500,
    items : [
        A
    ]
});
```

Comment: What is not working? What did you try?

Comment: What do you mean by full size of panel A? 1000,600? or the size of panel B?

Comment: 1000*600, sorry already updated the question. The prbolem is that no matter what I do, the size of panel A is limited by panel B.

Comment: well what did you expect? B is smaller than A ... Are you trying to expand B or make it scroll to show parts of A.

Comment: No I don't, that's why I'm asking if it's possible to resize the inner panel without resizing the outer one. I thought that suspendingLayouts will allow the parent panel to grow but guess it was fools hope.